# How is a picture from space displayed on a window?

Tags: vernor-vinge, marooned-in-real-time

*Marooned in Realtime*, page 39:

> “Anyway, the area around the Peace bobble is still a vitrified plain. It took her decades, but she built a sign there.” The window behind Yelén suddenly became a view from space. At that distance, the bobble was just a glint of sunlight with a spiky shadow. A jagged black line extended northwards from it. Apparently the picture was taken at local dawn, and the black strip was the shadow of Marta’s monument. It must have been several meters high and dozens of kilometers long. The image lasted only seconds, the space of time Yelén imagined it.

It’s a picture from space? On a window?
Why the image only lasted seconds?
It’s describing Marta’s bubble?

“You may not know this, but we have lots of equipment at the Lagrange zones. Some of it is in kiloyear stasis. Some is flickering with a period of decades. None of it is carefully watching the ground … but that line structure was enough to trip even a high-threshold monitor. Eventually, the robots sent a lander to investigate.… They were just a few years too late.” Wil forced his mind past thinking on what the lander found. Thank God Yelén’s imagination didn’t flash that on the windows.

What is flickering with a period of decades?
That line structure? It’s Marta’s monument?
Yeléns imagination could control the holográfic windows  ?
What is a kiloyear?

Comment: Please don't edit new questions into your question.  If you have a follow-on question, ask it separately and refer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

Earlier, when Wil arrives at the Korolev estate:

> The Korolev library had no bookcases weighted down with data cartridges or paper-and-ink books. Data could be accessed anywhere; the library was a place to sit and think (with appropriate support devices) or to hold a small conference. The walls were lined with holo windows showing the surrounding countryside.

It's not a window, it's a holographic display that was acting as a "window" and is now being used to display a view recorded from orbit.  The seconds-long view is merely as long as the camera in orbit was tasked to the scene.  It may even have been one of the automatic cameras that captured it:

> "You may not know this, but we have lots of equipment at the Lagrange zones. Some of
> it is in kiloyear stasis. Some is flickering with a period of decades. None of it is carefully watching the ground... but that line structure was enough to trip even a high-threshold monitor."